# sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'tuple' is not supported

Tags: python, list, sqlite3

При попытке обновления базы данных sqlite3 выводит вот такую ошибку: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'tuple' is not supported

Вот код:

```
def setinventory(msgid, added):
    sql.execute("UPDATE bank SET inventory = ? WHERE id = ?", (added, msgid))

g = list(get.getsql.getinventory(msgid))
g.append(message.text[8:])
get.getsql.setinventory(msgid, tuple(g))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Кст, а почему бы не все параметры передавать? `sql.execute("UPDATE bank SET inventory = ? WHERE id = ?", (added, msgid))`

Comment: Подправил в коде вопроса отступы, чтобы разделить код функции от ее вызова

Answer (score 1):

В `setinventory(msgid, added)` вы вызываете `sql.execute`, оборачивая аргументы (как `added`) в кортеж (`tuple`), чтобы был биндинг

Но при вызове `setinventory` вы еще раз в аргумент `added` передаете кортеж:

```
get.getsql.setinventory(msgid, tuple(g))
```

Передавайте как есть:

```
get.getsql.setinventory(msgid, g)
```

---

**UPD.**

Выяснилось, что есть вопросы получения данных из `getinventory`, а также хранения и добавления элементов как в список, но в строковом поле таблицы.

Реализация хранения нескольких элементов в одном строковом поле:

- Исправляем функцию `getinventory` - теперь она возвращает честное строковое значение
- Придумываем формат строки для нескольких элементов, пусть это будет по разделителю `", "`

Пример:

```
def getinventory(msgid: int) -> str:
    return sql.execute(f"SELECT inventory FROM bank WHERE id = ?", (msgid,)).fetchone()[0]

def setinventory(msgid: int, added: str):
    sql.execute("UPDATE bank SET inventory = ? WHERE id = ?", (added, msgid))

g = get.getsql.getinventory(msgid).split(", ")
g.append(message.text[8:])
get.getsql.setinventory(msgid, ", ".join(g))
```

Формат строки можно сделать надежнее, храня как список в `json` (но эта тема для другого вопроса :))

Comment: Теперь вот такая ошибка:
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'list' is not supported

Comment: @kwarsk, а зачем вы список передаете в `inventory = `? У вас там какой тип столбца?

Comment: sql.execute("UPDATE bank SET inventory = ? WHERE id = ?", (added, msgid))

Простите, где я передаю список в id?

Comment: @kwarsk, наверное, у вас в `inventory` строка (в sqlite3 нет типа списка, там простые типы). А в функции `getinventory` вы получаете из таблицы из той строки данные. Тогда, вам в `setinventory` передавать в том же формате данные из `g`. Как вариант, такие вещи как список из `g` приводить к строке json (хотя, для работы с базой лучше бы в отдельной таблице хранить)

Comment: я получаю данные в типе tuple, так как кортежи являются неизменяемым типом данных, я преобразую этот кортеж в список, добавляю данные, затем снова преобразую список в кортеж и передаю в функцию

Comment: @kwarsk, вы не ответили в каком типе и виде храните данные в `inventory` :) В функции `getinventory` вы наверняка берете данные из `inventory`, значит есть какой-то формат данные, раз вы его в виде коллекции получаете и планируете сохранять. Если нет или не знаете, то покажите функцию `getinventory`

Comment: Тип данных столбца inventory - TEXT
Функция getinventory:
def getinventory(msgid):
        return sql.execute(f"SELECT inventory FROM bank WHERE id = {msgid}").fetchall()

Comment: @kwarsk, `fetchall` возвращает все результаты из базы. У вас там `id = `, а значит результат всегда будет один. Причем, у вас хоть и возвращается 1 поле, но оно будет обернуто в кортеж. Итого, вы возвращаете список из кортежа на 1 элемент. Если в `inventory` у вас была строка `"abc"`, то с `fetchall` вернется `[("abc",)]`. Правильно использовать `fetchone` и вытаскивать из кортежа данные. Итого: `def getinventory(msgid): return sql.execute(f"SELECT inventory FROM bank WHERE id = ?", (msgid,)).fetchone()[0]`

Comment: @kwarsk, теперь `getinventory` будет возвращать строку из таблицы. Теперь вопрос как в ней хранить несколько элементов, т.к. есть `message.text[8:]`, я бы предложил json (а лучше в отдельной таблице), но можно каким-то разделителем, пусть будет `" ,"`, тогда `g = get.getsql.getinventory(msgid).split(" ,")`, а перед добавлением в `get.getsql.setinventory(msgid, " ,".join(g))`

Comment: Можно ли как-то обойтись со списком или кортежем?

Comment: @kwarsk, в базе нет такого типа, как я выше писал. Вы либо список в виде строки складываете в поле (тогда уж в json, т.к. вариант с разделителем `", "` имеет большой минус из-за разделителя), либо заводите еще таблицу в ней элементы списка храните и параллельно строите связь этой таблицы к таблице `bank`. А так, метод `.split(" ,")` вернет **список** из строк, а перед добавлением через `" ,".join(` вы этот список объедините в строку по разделителю